# Apply a filter str_replace on specific caracters array in the_content()

Tags: filters, the-content

I am trying to create a filter for `the_content()` where I would be able to aply a `str_replace()` on specific caracters array().

At the moment, I have it working for only one caracter. I would like to be

```
function str_replace_special_caracter($content) {

    // My array of special caracters to get <sup>
    $specialCaracters = array('®', '™');

        // Special code to filter in array?

    // Return
    return str_replace('®', '<sup>®</sup>', $content);

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'str_replace_special_caracter', 99 );
```

This simple solution is working. But as I may have new special caracter to place a `<sup></sup>` an array will be better.

**Possible solution?**

I saw people using `strstr` [PHP Function](http://php.net/strtr) and when I tried it, it did not quite worked. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

```
function str_replace_special_caracter($content) {

    // My array of special caracters to get <sup>
    $specialCaracters = array('®' => '<sup>®</sup>', '™' => '<sup>™</sup>');

        // Special code to filter in array?

    // Return
    return strstr($content, $specialCaracters);

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'str_replace_special_caracter', 99 );
```

Resulting in an error : `Warning: strstr(): needle is not a string or an integer in /home/.../functions.php on line 186`

Everything I found on Stackexchange are "double-array" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399286/str-replace-with-associative-array)

I'll keep investing, but if some one has a clue how I could do it, it would be nice.

Comment: look what is in `$content`, it can be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could obtain what you need like this:

```
function str_replace_special_caracter($content) {

    // My array of special caracters to get <sup>
    $specialCaracters = array('®', '™');

    foreach( $specialCaracters as $character ){

        $content = preg_replace( '@(' . preg_quote( $character, '@' ) . ')@i', "<sup>\\1</sup>", $content );

    }

    // Return
    return $content;

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'str_replace_special_caracter', 99 );
```

Comment: Looks like it is working. I'm not a "super-user" of `preg_replace`. I will have to read some documentation but your anwser fixed my problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer to remove the '\b' from the preg_replace as with it only characters that where at the beginning of a word would have been found. But that is not what you need.

Comment: Alright ! It is good to know.